# jquery image rezise not working in chrome

Tags: jquery

Hi all im working on a little image resize script and it works in ie and ff but not in chrome. I have to refresh the page to get it to work. I am working in an iframe. Heres my code

```
 function resize() {
    var maxWidth = 200;

    var width = $("#ImageMainPicture").width();
    //alert(width);
    if (width > maxWidth) {
        $("#ImageMainPicture").css("width", maxWidth);
    }
```

This is called on a jquery doc.ready.

Thanks to all who look at this

Comment: Just to note you are missing the ending `}` for the function. This would cause an error or issues..but perhaps its just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready()` runs before the image is loaded. When you need media to be loaded, use `$(window).load(` instead.

Alternatively, just use CSS!

```
#ImageMainPicture {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: You my friend are a hero. Sometimes i complicate things when an easy answer is available

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("#ImageMainPicture").width(maxWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following if "#ImageMainPicture" is Image Element because image is not loaded when $(document).ready(), so you suppose to put that code in $(window).load()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){
    var maxWidth = 200;
    var width = $("#ImageMainPicture").outerWidth();
    if (width > maxWidth) {
        $("#ImageMainPicture").css("width", maxWidth);
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function resize() {
    var $img = $("img#ImageMainPicture");

    $img.onload(function () {
        var onloadInterval = setInterval(function () {
            // Make sure the image is actually loaded in IE
            if ($img[0].complete) {
                clearInterval(onloadInterval);
                $img.css("width", Math.min($img[0].width, 200));
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}
```

Calling the function will find the image with an id of "ImageMainPicture" and set the onload to start an interval. The interval checks for the complete property on the image object so that we're sure the image is loaded in IE, and then sets the width of the image to the whichever value is smaller.

This way we're absolutely sure that the image is there for us to manipulate it's width.